# Skrollr issues with anchor-targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm attempting to roll divs over one another as your scroll down a page using Skrollr. I've gotten the desired effect to work with two divs, but when I try to make it work with a 3rd, only the first and last div seem to work. I'm thinking this is because I'm not fully understanding how the data-anchor-target attribute in Skrollr works. Here is the HTML I'm attempting to use:

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
        <div id="q1" data-0="top:0%;">
            Text
        </div>
        <div id="q2" data-anchor-target="#q1" data--200-bottom="top:100%;" data-top-bottom="top:0%;">
            Text2
        </div>
        <div id="q3" data-anchor-target="#q2" data--200-bottom="top:100%;" data-top-bottom="top:0%;">
            Text3
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#skrollr-body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
#skrollr-body > div {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#q1 {
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RtoJ2papsoA/UhicT91ixmI/AAAAAAAACeg/2XEhv26ZFJc/s1600/jghjgh.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#q2 {
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RtoJ2papsoA/UhicT91ixmI/AAAAAAAACeg/2XEhv26ZFJc/s1600/jghjgh.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#q3 {
    background: url(http://iwritealot.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/golden-clouds-wallpaper.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YMYTy/)

What am I missing that is not allowing all 3 divs to behave as expected, instead of just the first and last?

Thanks.

Comment: anchor-target doesn't work this way, because you are manipulating the target itself. You should be able to get this effect with it. Basically you need to set position to fixed as soon as the element itself reaches the top (data-top).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example without anchor-target http://jsfiddle.net/YMYTy/1/

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
    <div id="q1">
        Text
    </div>
    <div id="q2" data-bottom-top="top:100%;" data-top="top:0%;">
        Text2
    </div>
    <div id="q3" data-bottom-top="top:100%;" data-top="top:0%;">
        Text3
    </div>
</div>
```

It's different than what I described, but works.

There's this open feature request which, once implemented, will make this much easier https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/185 You will then be able to use `data-100p` and `data-200p` to have animations after you scrolled down one or two times the height of the viewport.

Comment: This seems to give an effect really close to what I'm looking for. I'm playing with it now to see what I can make it do. Thanks a bunch!